# Haskell: Function which use user definied data type

Tags: haskell

I have written following data type and its instance in Haskell:

```
data Plaster = Plaster [String] deriving (Read, Show)

examplePlaster :: Plaster
examplePlaster = Plaster ["..AEG", "..CD", "DC...", "A.B.", "..EFG"]
```

I would like to create a function, which applicated to `examplePlaster` returns the first String on a list. How should I do that?

Comment: It looks like you don't need a wrapping type for the `[String]`, you could just use a type synonym: `type Plaster = [String]` and then use the `head` function or pattern match on the `:` constructor in order to get the first item in the list.

Answer (score 6):

Like any other type, you can pattern match on the value created by your data constructor.

```
getFirst :: Plaster -> Maybe String
getFirst (Plaster (x:xs)) = Just x
getFirst (Plaster []) = Nothing
```

Comment: You could write that second part as `getFirst _ = Nothing` if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `head` function from `Data.List`

```
getFirst :: Plaster -> String
getFirst (Plaster []) = "" 
getFirst (Plaster xs) = head xs
```

Where `head :: [a] -> a` extract the first element of a list, which must be non-empty. As explained [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:1).

And to call it do: `getFirst examplePlaster`